# Kill a process in Unix

Tags: unix, process, kill, ps

When I execute the`ps -fea | grep ssh-agent` command, I get the following output:

```
tomcat   29057 14086   0   Jan 09 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
oracle   1964  14086   0   Nov 26 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   13654 14086   0   Nov 13 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      11818 14086   0   Jan 14 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
oracle   24987 14086   0   Nov 14 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   20107 14086   0   Dec 13 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   12540 14086   0   Oct 17 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
xoib240  5702  14086   0   Oct 16 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
root     11199 14086   0   Oct 11 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      10414 14086   0   Oct 11 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
usuariop 1661  14086   0   Oct 05 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   13416 14086   0   Oct 18 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   14680 14086   0   Jan 10 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
tomcat   19067 14086   0   Nov 09 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
oracle   13196 14086   0   Nov 26 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      12158 14086   0   Sep 27 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      1206  14086   0   Jan 25 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      20821 14086   0   Jan 29 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
xoi3ef8  13888 14086   0   Oct 08 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
sgp      20894 14086   0   Jan 24 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
root     22907 14086   0   Jan 14 ?           0:00 ssh-agent
```

I want to know if why I can't kill this process.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall

Comment: I ain't no Spanish expert, but I assume "eliminar" means "to eliminate, to kill" - edited the title in order it to be English.

Comment: your list shows 21 processes.  "kill this process" implies that you want to kill one process.  which process do you want to kill?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`killall`](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) command.

```
killall ssh-agent
```

Comment: ... and run that as root as the various processes are running under a variety of users.

Comment: Is it safe to kill these processes or these processes are consuming resources

Answer (score 0):

You can kill these processes, but it will impact on your ability to log in to other ssh servers from that box.   (ssh-agent remembers your private key so you don't need to type it in again).

If a process is stubborn, you can often use "kill -9 (processid)" to force it to die.  My understanding is that this is akin to "pulling the plug" on the process to kill it immediately rather then "pressing the off button" to signal it should shut down.  I would be a bit surprised if you could not kill this process with just a killall ssh-agent though.

Comment: So, i do not need to remove processes?, can i leave them there

Comment: You don't need to remove the processes.  They are probably taking a bit of ram thats all.  Also, if you kill them they will probably come back next time you start your system.